# org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:

Tags: java, spring, jsp, maven, pom.xml

Hi all I am new in Spring, maven,jsp,Servlet. When I am running my project I am getting this error. please let me know what should I do, I am providing all the details bellow. Thanks in advance

Error
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:

**Directory Structure**
[image]

URL-http://localhost:8080/my-app/ContactForm.jsp

**POM.XML**

```html
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.mycompany.app</groupId>
  <artifactId>my-app</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>my-app</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  
  <properties>
    <java.version>1.7</java.version>
    <spring.version>3.2.13.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <cglib.version>2.2.2</cglib.version>
 </properties> 
   
  <dependencies>
  
  <!-- Spring Core & MVC -->
  
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.13.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
 
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.13.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.13.RELEASE</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    
    <!-- CGLib for @Configuration -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>cglib</groupId>
        <artifactId>cglib-nodep</artifactId>
        <version>2.1_2</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    
    <!-- Servlet Specifiaction -->
  
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
   <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency> 
    
    <dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
     <version>3.0.7.RELEASE</version>
 </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

**Controller class**

```html
package net.codejava.spring.controller;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

import net.codejava.spring.dao.ContactDAO;
import net.codejava.spring.model.Contact;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import antlr.collections.List;


public class HomeController {
 
 @Autowired
  private ContactDAO contactDAO;
 
 @RequestMapping(value="/")
 public ModelAndView listContact(ModelAndView model) throws IOException{
     List listContact = (List) contactDAO.list();
     model.addObject("listContact", listContact);
     model.setViewName("home");
  
     return model;
 }
 
 
 @RequestMapping(value = "/newContact", method = RequestMethod.GET)
 public ModelAndView newContact(ModelAndView model) {
     Contact newContact = new Contact();
     model.addObject("contact", newContact);
     model.setViewName("ContactForm");
     return model;
 }
 
 @RequestMapping(value = "/saveContact", method = RequestMethod.POST)
 public ModelAndView saveContact(@ModelAttribute Contact contact) {
     contactDAO.saveOrUpdate(contact);
     return new ModelAndView("redirect:/");
 }
 
 @RequestMapping(value = "/deleteContact", method = RequestMethod.GET)
 public ModelAndView deleteContact(HttpServletRequest request) {
     int contactId = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id"));
     contactDAO.delete(contactId);
     return new ModelAndView("redirect:/");
 }
 
 @RequestMapping(value = "/editContact", method = RequestMethod.GET)
 public ModelAndView editContact(HttpServletRequest request) {
     int contactId = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id"));
     Contact contact = contactDAO.get(contactId);
     ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("ContactForm");
     model.addObject("contact", contact);
  
     return model;
 }
 

}
```

**MvcConfiguration.java**

```html
package net.codejava.spring.config;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import net.codejava.spring.dao.ContactDAO;
import net.codejava.spring.dao.ContactDAOImpl;
 
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;


@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages="net.codejava.spring")
@EnableWebMvc

public class MvcConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
 
  @Bean
     public ViewResolver getViewResolver(){
         InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
         resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/");
         resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
         return resolver;
     }
  
  @Override
     public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
         registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
     }

  @Bean
     public DataSource getDataSource() {
         DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
         dataSource.setDriverClassName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
         dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:oracle://localhost:1521/orcl");
         dataSource.setUsername("system");
         dataSource.setPassword("admin");
          
         return dataSource;
     }
  
  @Bean
     public ContactDAO getContactDAO() {
         return new ContactDAOImpl(getDataSource());
     }
}
```

Comment: Full stacktrace please ? It seems like *u missed to add dependency for Jasper reports library.* Check out [Jasper Maven Dependency](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sf.jasperreports/jasperreports)

Comment: @Kenneth Clark Have u go through `pom.xml` in question ? `javax.servlet` is in provided scope.

Comment: What is the status now ?

Comment: HTTP Status 404 - /my-app/ContactForm.jsp

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

type Status report

message /my-app/ContactForm.jsp

description The requested resource (/my-app/ContactForm.jsp) is not available.


--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Comment: @Kenneth Clark please help me should I post my hole code ??

Comment: It's very clear from the error, the application is unable to find the `ContactForm.jsp` page. Where it is located ? Can u add directory structure & URL ?

Comment: What I am trying to do is  to create  an application which will help me to understand the Spring flow using spring ,maven, jsp and oracle. the application suppose to fetch the data from database and display on jsp. user can create contact and display it on another jsp. I followed some tutorial and trying to implement the same. This can help lot of people who are new in this.

Comment: See your `ContactForm.jsp` is inside `WEB-INF` directory & as u r using Spring, you have to create `viewResolver` using `InternalResourceViewResolver` in `dispatcher-servlet.xml` Have u added this ? If not, then u must. **All the resources inside `WEB-INF` directory are considered as protected.**

Comment: I have created a java class called "MvcConfiguration" and providing the configuration into that. can you please check that class.

Comment: I think you have to create an implementer for `WebApplicationInitializer` so that your app knows about dispatcher servlet mapping i.e */, the baseUrl of app*. Or create an XML file & add `viewResolver` in it & then add context param `contextConfigLocation` in Web.xml.

Comment: Have u created `WebApplicationInitializer ` ? What is the status now ?

Comment: Friend I am trying to do with the java configuration file and its not working yet I checked hole thing once gain but still not working

Comment: Checkout [ViewResolver using Annotation](http://outbottle.com/spring-4-web-mvc-hello-world-using-annotation-configuration-with-netbeans/) & [ViewResolver in dispatcher-servlet.xml](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/spring/mvc/spring-mvc-view-resolver-example/). I hope this will definitely solves ur problem. If it, then I'll add an answer to ur question so that others facing same problem get solution & u can then accept my answer.